# Iterate df.loc through a list until it finds a numerical value/ does not error?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Basically I want to use df.loc to grep values from a dataframe.
The workflow goes like is:

1. If df.loc finds a value (doesn't error), set variable = that string
2. If df.loc cannot find a value and errors, move to the next item in the list to df.loc.
3. If df.loc cannot find a value for all items in the list, set variable = 0.

I think the code should look something like this:

```
revenue_list = ['Revenues', 'RevenueFromContractWithCustomerExcludingAssessedTax', 'TotalRevenues']

for i in revenue_list:
  revenue_list = (0 if len(df.loc[[i]].sort_values(['fp', 'end'], ascending=[True, False]).iloc[0]['val'])==0 
                     else df.loc[[i]].sort_values(['fp', 'end'], ascending=[True, False]).iloc[0]['val'])
  if revenue_list != 0:
    break;
```

Here is an example dataframe that im grepping from:

```
{'accn': {'RevenueFromContractWithCustomerExcludingAssessedTax': '0001783879-21-000029'},
 'cik': {'RevenueFromContractWithCustomerExcludingAssessedTax': '1783879'},
 'end': {'RevenueFromContractWithCustomerExcludingAssessedTax': datetime.date(2020, 6, 30)},
 'enddate_minus_startdate': {'RevenueFromContractWithCustomerExcludingAssessedTax': 181.0},
 'filed': {'RevenueFromContractWithCustomerExcludingAssessedTax': '2021-08-18'},
 'form': {'RevenueFromContractWithCustomerExcludingAssessedTax': '10-Q'},
 'fp': {'RevenueFromContractWithCustomerExcludingAssessedTax': 'Q2'},
 'frame': {'RevenueFromContractWithCustomerExcludingAssessedTax': nan},
 'fy': {'RevenueFromContractWithCustomerExcludingAssessedTax': 2021},
 'start': {'RevenueFromContractWithCustomerExcludingAssessedTax': datetime.date(2020, 1, 1)},
 'ticker': {'RevenueFromContractWithCustomerExcludingAssessedTax': 'hood'},
 'val': {'RevenueFromContractWithCustomerExcludingAssessedTax': 283044000.0}}
```

Comment: I would set at start `variable = 0` and next run `for`-loop to change it to other value. If it will not find element then it will keep `variable = 0`. And inside `for`-loop I would use `try/except` to catch error.

Comment: don't use the same name of variable `revenue_list` for different values.

Comment: you should example dataframe - but you could also show expected result for this data. And it could be simpler if you show other example dataframes which should give different results.

Comment: Awesome that first approach worked. Thank you!